# Probability of A and not B

Tags: probability

I'm studying Introduction to probability and currently, I'm stuck with the following problem. Given:

$P(A)=0.7$,
$P(B)=0.5$,
$P(A\cap B)=0.45$

What is the probability of A and not B?

I've checked this similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134251/probability-of-only-a-but-not-b-ocurring) but I don't understand the answers. Also I've asked my instructor and she told me that $1-P(A\cap B)(P(B^c))$ is the answer *(As the answers suggested, this result is not correct)*. Why is that? She does not provided me a completely explanation.

**Update 1: The original problem is the following**

In a multiplex cinema, there are two different rooms, $A$ and $B$, working simultaneously. Let $SA$ be the event that, during a certain showing, room $A$ becomes full before the film begins, and let $SB$ be the event that, during the same showing, room $B$ becomes full before the beginning of the movie. We know that $P(SA)=0.7$; $P(SB)=0.5$ and $P(SA∩SB)=0.45$

Calculate the probability that room $A$ will become full and room $B$ will not.

Did I state the problem correctly?

**Update 2: Add a Venn diagram**. Following the advice of Ethan Bolker. Here is the Venn diagram that I made.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you stated the problem and the solution correctly? For the question you asked you do not need to know the probability of $B$, and the answer you were given is wrong.

Comment: Maybe I stated the problem wrong. I update my question to add the original problem. I stated the solution correctly, it is wrong?

Comment: I am still confused. Your restatement does not add information. Perhaps there is missing information about customers arriving and choosing one of the rooms with a certain probability. I think you will have to get more clarification from your instructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine A to be a line segment of length 0.7 and B to be a line segment of length 0.5 that overlap by a distance of 0.45.

For example A could be [0, 0.7] and B [0.25, 0.75].  Then A union "not B" is [0, 0.25] so has probability 0.25.

Comment: That's the exact same solution my instructor gave me. How can I see this in "probability language" instead of segments?

Comment: @DennisConcepciónMartín: In probability language, with the visualization suggested, you should be able to see that the answer is $P(A) - P(A\cap B)$

Comment: After a coffee break I could understand it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try drawing a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$P(A \cap \overline{B}) = P(A\setminus(A\cap B)) = P(A) - P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: It gives me the correct solution but I do not fully understand the reasoning. I'll study more. Thank you.

Comment: @DennisConcepciónMartín Actually, there is nothing done with the probabilities, only some transformation of set operations.